# iOS Launch Image Confusion

Tags: ios, launchimage

I've read every post about launch images and I'm still confused about the status bar.  I understand that iPad launch images should exclude the status bar and iPhone launch images should INclude the status bar.  I can see that iPad image sizes have the size of the status bar knocked off, so that is no problem.

However, I included the status bar on my iPhone launch images, but when the app launches the actual device status bar appears to bleed through as though the status bar on my image as the launch image fades, which looks lousy.

My question is whether it would be acceptable to have the iPhone images be the correct size but to not actually SHOW the status bar in the image (i.e., in my case, it would just be plain white)?

This would create a better looking launch image in my case but I'm unclear on what Apple is wanting here.  Thx.

EDIT:

Apparently, all launch images are now required to include the status bar, including the iPad.  I suppose this changed with XCode5.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a problem ever since iOS 7 introduced the see-through status bar.

You will have to write some code that creates a special initial interface of your app, so that it hides the status bar on launch and you can take the screen shot. (This seems, indeed, to be the strategy you are proposing.)

Either that or, as is sometimes possible, take the screen shot and then cover the status bar in Photoshop or similar with a rectangle of the correct color.

The problem is solved, or close to it, in Xcode 6, where you can make a launch image from Interface Builder directly based on the Preview of your interface that it provides. Since the launch image is usually a very rudimentary version of the interface, and since Xcode 6 lets you draw the preview details with `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, it is usually possible to create a good launch image without bothering to write an alternate launch routine just to get the screen shot.

Comment: So, I'm supplying launch images where I've just whited out the status bar portion of the image (which matches my app's background).  But all images will be the same size as the screen, as when I tried to crop the status bar out of the iPad image XCode gave me a warning it was not the correct size.  It looks as though I had gotten the incorrect size for iPad somewhere on the Internet.  Thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy: Include the status bar region, but don't include the actual content of the statusbar. So for example the iPhone 5 launch image would be 640 x 1136 pixels.

If you have a non-solid statusbar background color you should use something like [SDScreenshotCapture](http://shinydevelopment.com/status-magic/translucent-screenshots-help/) to take screenshots. This class creates a screenshot without the status bar content.